# Java List/Array List clarification

Tags: java, list, arraylist, return-value, new-operator

If someone can explain the difference between these two type of Array Initializations that would be great:

There is a static method `getList()` in class `ListReturn`, which returns an `ArrayList<Some_Custom_Object>` upon calling.

In the invoking class, I can call the function in two ways as follows:

1. `List<Some_Custom_Object> listFromCall = new ArrayList<Some_Custom_Object>();`
   `listFromCall=ListReturn.getList();//works completely fine`
2. `List<Some_Custom_Object> listFromCall = ListReturn.getList();//Works completely fine`

My question here is, in the second scenario, don't we have to initialize or instantiate the listFromCall object?, can we directly assign return values from method to un-initialized List/ArrayList object?

Can someone please explain what is going on beneath the hood here?.

Thanks

Comment: `ListReturn` ? is this any standard class ? If not then it will depend upon impementation.

Comment: Number 1 looks like it was written by someone who doesn't know what they are doing. There's no point assigning a new `ArrayList` to a variable you are immediately going to set to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss both way one by one,

**First Way :**

1. `List<Some_Custom_Object> listFromCall = new ArrayList<Some_Custom_Object>();`

means, something likewise,

[image]

```
listFromCall=ListReturn.getList();//works completely fine
```

> it will reflect on *listFromCall*'s value assignment, see below image for
>   deeper understanding,

[image]

> Here, completion of both statement, total either 2-object created(1
>   will eligible for garbage collection after second created and assign)
>   or 1-object created (which will become eligible for garbage collection
>   and assign null to reference variable)

**Your Second Way :**

Now if you do something likewise,

```
2.    List<Some_Custom_Object> listFromCall = ListReturn.getList();//Works completely fine
```

Then it will appear something likewise,

[image]

> So, here either `1-object(of ArrayList)` will created on heap or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation,I really appreciate you taking time to explain this.I have just one query .In the second approach diagram, shouldn't that be an OR between null value and return value of ListReturn.getList(); method.

Comment: @RookieHere into second approach might be possible not created instance in that case will assign null otherwise instance

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Mr.Vishal

Answer (score 2):

You only have to initialize a variable if you read from it before you write to it.

If you write to an uninitialized variable, the computer doesn't care because you're initializing it with the return value from `ListReturn.getList()`.

In fact, you shouldn't needlessly initialize object variables to anything but `null` if they're going to be overwritten before use. Otherwise, you create and garbage collect an extra object for no reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the point of creating and GCing an extra object makes sense.Thanks